# Cannot call DLL import entry, C# -> C++, EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, name-decoration

I'm trying to call from C# a function in a custom DLL written in C++. However I'm getting the warning during code analysis and the error at runtime:

> Warning: CA1400 :
>   Microsoft.Interoperability : Correct
>   the declaration of
>   'SafeNativeMethods.SetHook()' so that
>   it correctly points to an existing
>   entry point in 'wi.dll'. The unmanaged
>   entry point name currently linked to
>   is SetHook.
>
> Error:
>   System.EntryPointNotFoundException was
>   unhandled. Unable to find an entry
>   point named 'SetHook' in DLL 'wi.dll'.

Both projects wi.dll and C# exe has been compiled in to the same DEBUG folder, both files reside here. There is only one file with the name wi.dll in the whole file system.

C++ function definition looks like:

```
#define WI_API __declspec(dllexport)
bool WI_API SetHook();
```

I can see exported function using Dependency Walker:

```
as decorated: bool SetHook(void)
as undecorated: ?SetHook@@YA_NXZ
```

C# DLL import looks like (I've defined these lines using CLRInsideOut from MSDN magazine):

```
[DllImport("wi.dll", EntryPoint = "SetHook", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I1)]
internal static extern bool SetHook();
```

I've tried without EntryPoint and CallingConvention definitions as well.

Both projects are 32-bits, I'm using W7 64 bits, VS 2010 RC.

I believe that I simply have overlooked something....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you know the entry point name, use the EntryPoint = "?SetHook@@YA_NXZ" property in the [DllImport] attribute.  Or put extern "C" before the declaration in your C++ code so the name doesn't get mangled.

```
[DllImport("wi.dll", EntryPoint = "?SetHook@@YA_NXZ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I1)]
internal static extern bool SetHook();
```

Comment: Great! That helped, I've put extern "C" before declaration.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Put __stdcall in the declaration as well, saves you from having to use CallingConvention.

Answer (score 1):

`CallingConvention.Cdecl` means C not C++, so when you have a function with a C++ decorated name, you need to use the decorated name as your `EntryPoint` or use Extern "C" in The C++ code declaration to turn off C++ name decoration.