# bool type equivalent for calling Unmanaged C++ API from C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmanaged

I am getting ***System.EntryPointNotFoundException*** while calling an Unmanaged method (C++) from C# which takes 'bool' as argument.

Following is the **function declaration in C++**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall MethodA(bool Flag);
```

I used the **following code in C#** which I found after searching for a while. But I still get the same exception.

```
[DllImport("UnmanagedDLL.dll")]
private static extern void MethodA([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] bool Flag);
```

I also tried using *Byte*, *Boolean* & *int* types instead of bool, still i get same exception.

Please someone give me a solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance
User2794477

Comment: see last post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465243/cannot-call-dll-import-entry-c-sharp-c-entrypointnotfoundexception

Comment: As far as I know you cannot call functions in C++ DLLs directly because they get a new name by the compiler (name mangling). You'd need to build the DLL with C++/CLI to be able to call a function from C# in it or use `extern "C"` around the function declaration.

Comment: @Јοеу, The easier way is to use `extern "C"`.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for the response. I checked that link and found it is the problem with the name mangling. So, I gave EntryPoint as the same name which I found in the .lib file of DLL and it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its a lot of effort to add extern "C", instead I used exact name from lib file as entrypoint. It worked. Thanks @Joey